# Error Loading Class solr.ICUCollationKeyFilterFactory

Tags: java, solr

I am updating a Solr instance from 4.0 to 4.6 and running into some issues. I am not that familiar with Java.

How do I find the jar file that has the `ICUCollationKeyFilterFactory` class? Is there a website to search for classes and what jar you will need?

Updating Solr 4.0 to 4.6 on Tomcat 7.

```
test: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "icu_sort_string": 
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: 
Error loading class 'solr.ICUCollationKeyFilterFactory'. 
Schema file is /Users/chall/solr/solr-4.6.0/multicore/test/schema.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what would be the best way to find it, but searching for 'icu' with a simple find (or similar depending on your OS) would give you this:

```
lucene-4.6.0\analysis\icu\lucene-analyzers-icu-4.6.0.jar
```

If you peek inside the jar (is like a zip) you can find the class in there.